# text ellipsis not working in css inside table

Tags: css

```
td:nth-child(1) {
    max-width: 130px !important;

    div {
      a {
        max-width: 120px !important;
        outline: 1px solid red;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
      }
    }
  }
```

**text ellipsis is not working , i tried using ellipsis inside td in table. it seems to work when width is not specified and ellipsis is applied in td(parent contaienr) i used width too still it dosent work**

Comment: Can you place this code in https://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: Can you provide it's HTML structure, that you are using for table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it "display: inline-block"

```css
td div a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div><a>Make it "display: inline-block"</a></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a couple of methods

- Use `display: block` or `display: inline-block` to the `a` tag.
- Provide `float: left` or `float: right` to the `a` tag.

Don't forgot to provide a fixed `width` or `max-width` to one of it's parent container.

```css
/* using display: inline-block or dislay: block */

td:nth-child(2)>div {
  max-width: 300px;
}

td:nth-child(2)>div>a {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block; // or block;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>
        <div><a href="#">Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content dfidjfdfd</a></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```css
/* using float: left and float: right */

td:nth-child(2)>div {
  max-width: 300px;
}

td:nth-child(2)>div>a {
  width: 100%;
  float: left; // or right
  outline: 1px solid red;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>
        <div><a href="#">Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content dfidjfdfd</a></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

give width to perent so it will prevent the text to go out of the box, you are trying to set width to text so it can't be overflowed.

```
td:nth-child(1) {

div {
  width:125px;
  a {
    outline: 1px solid red;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
}
```

}